# Integrity protection warning in Bouncy Castle Encryption in Android App

Tags: java, android, pgp, openpgp

With reference to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216302/11662832)

I am getting a the following warning :

```
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected
gpg: Hint: If this message was created before the year 2003 it is
     likely that this message is legitimate.  This is because back
     then integrity protection was not widely used.
gpg: Use the option '--ignore-mdc-error' to decrypt anyway.
```

It is completely ignorable. But I want to resolve it. Going through the BCGPG stuff on internet I narrowed down the issue to what I think the problem is.

```
 PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()));
```

I think the problem arises on

> BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES)

as **SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES** is a quite old method of encryption. Moreover the key pair are asymmetric hence there should be some other asymmetric algorithms to use in code. I am not getting the correct way to implement other methods such as AES and SHA.

Although I am not 100% sure on this, can suggest more insight on solving this.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what the message says. Integrity protection is described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.13

I believe that the code you are referencing is not setting the [withIntegrityPacket](https://borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/pg/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/operator/bc/BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder.html#setWithIntegrityPacket(boolean)) flag on the [BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder](https://borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/pg/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/operator/bc/BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder.html)

So I would change:

```
PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()));
```

to:

```
PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.TRIPLE_DES).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setWithIntegrityPacket(true));
```

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer ist still correct, but it should be mentioned that TRIPLE_DES should not be used. If you have this line i would suggest to change it for using AES_256 instead.

```
PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
    new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256)
    .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
    .setWithIntegrityPacket(true));
```